# Getting Two Added Values from A single Listbox c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

So in my program it should be able to solve our grade base on our school system. 
 I have two textboxes , a single button and a single listbox, when I pressed the button it would get two different values from the textboxes and put it in a listbox. Now my problem is how do I get the two different values of summation from those two textboxes, . AFter i got the two values i would just simply divide those up and get my answer, sorry for my bad english, also i am new to this proggraming.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listbox.Items.Add(string.Format("Unit\tGrade\tEquivalent"));
}
double grade = 0;
private void genbox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double units = Convert.ToDouble(unitval.Text);

    if (g.Text == "A" || g.Text=="a")
    {
        grade = 4;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "B+" || g.Text == "b+")
    {
        grade = 3.5;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "B" || g.Text == "b")
    {
        grade = 3;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "C+" || g.Text == "c+")
    {
        grade = 2.5;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "C" || g.Text == "c")
    {
        grade = 2;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "D" || g.Text == "d")
    {
        grade = 1;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "F" || g.Text == "f")
    {
        grade = 0;
    }
    else if (g.Text == "FD" || g.Text == "Fd" || g.Text == "fd" || g.Text == "fD")
    {
        grade = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Grade is not Determined");
        return;
    }

    g.Clear();
    unitval.Clear();
    double equiv = units * grade;

    listbox.Items.Add(units + "\t" + grade + "\t" + equiv );

    double tunits =+ units;
    double tequiv =+ equiv;

    double qpival = tequiv / tunits;

    qpi.Text = qpival.ToString();

}
```

Comment: I know the part 
 double tunits =+ units; -- > qpit.Text = qpival.ToString();
is waaay messed up

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a cast:

```
listbox.Items.Add(units + "\t" + grade + "\t" + equiv );
```

units, grade and equiv are declared as double

This should do the trick:

```
listbox.Items.Add(units.ToString() + "\t" + grade.ToString() + "\t" + equiv.ToString() );
```

Edit:

```
listbox.Items.Add(string.Format("Unit\tGrade\tEquivalent"));
```

String.Format doesn't work that way,
it is meant to be:

```
String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", parameter0, parameter1, parameter2);
```

So you can reformat your code to

```
listbox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", units.ToString(), grade.ToString(), equiv.ToString()));
```

Comment: Can i ask for the code on how to get the summations then?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it directly on C#, try doing it on pseudo-code and translate it to C# then, it would be clear for you once you have the algorithm designed.

It soulds like you want to put the adittion of units and grade and put it on the listbox right?

So i don't know if it is `double equiv = units * grade;` or `double equiv = units + grade;`
Also, the part where you are adding the values to the totals, it seems like you want those variables to be global so put them outside the method.

Comment: with due respect, what i want is to  divide the summation of units by the summation of equiv. and no, i would just like to use it in a single button_click method

Comment: Alright so your algorithm seems to be okay if you say so, so i ask, why is this part messed up?: `qpi.Text = qpival.ToString();`, it shouldn't throw any error since i guess qpi is already declared.

Comment: oh i am sorry, it is not error-based messed up. It is messed up , because it     will only solve and show the recent textboxes value rather of getting the summation. e.g ( Units = 4   and   3 ) ( Grades = 1 , 2) ( equiv = 4, 6) . the qpi value shown is   2( based on 6/3) rather it should show  1.428 ( based on 10/7) so my summation is messed up

Comment: Store the results of each operation in separate List<double> and then do a  list.Sum() of the values to get the summatory of each value.

Comment: can you do it in code mode, i can't understand sorry i am very new to proggraming hope u understand

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (g.Text == "F" || g.Text == "f")
```

To this:

```
if(g.Text.ToUpper().Equals("F"))
```

Change all if , to:

```
private int getGrade(string x)
{
if( .... ) { return ...; }
if( .... ) { return ...; }
}
```

Maybe you should change ListBox to ListWiev, you use Listbox like a table, you can get table in ListWiev.